# why is ResponseEntity <List<Object>> returning null?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, resttemplate

I have the following code and  it works with getMapping("/users/{userId}") but it does not return the list of users and displays "Internal server error "

I have attached the code for the classes I have used and I have even created another class which contains list of User to be used instead of `List<User>` but it did not work and the output was null , so I would be gratefull if anyone could help me about it .

//User

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {

    private  int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int price;
    private float discountPercentage ;
         private float rating ;
         private int stock;
         private String brand;
         private String category;
         private String thumbnail;
         private String[] images;


    public User() {
    }
}
```

//UserService

```
 public List<User> getUsers() {
    ResponseEntity<List<User>> responseEntity=restTemplate.exchange("https://dummyjson.com/
     produts/",HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<User>>(){
            });
  List<User> users= responseEntity.getBody();
   return users;
}
```

//UserController

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers(){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>( userService.getUsers(),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

//JSON

```
{
    "User": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "iPhone 9",
            "description": "An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
            "price": 549,
            "discountPercentage": 12.96,
            "rating": 4.69,
            "stock": 94,
            "brand": "Apple",
            "category": "smartphones",
            "thumbnail": "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
            "images": [
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/1.jpg",
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/2.jpg",
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/3.jpg",
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/4.jpg",
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/thumbnail.jpg"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "iPhone X",
            "description": "SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...",
            "price": 899,
            "discountPercentage": 17.94,
            "rating": 4.44,
            "stock": 34,
            "brand": "Apple",
            "category": "smartphones",
            "thumbnail": "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/thumbnail.jpg",
            "images": [
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/1.jpg",
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/2.jpg",
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/3.jpg",
                "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/thumbnail.jpg"
            ]
        }
],
    "total": 100,
    "skip": 0,
    "limit": 30
}
```

//Error

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [java.util.List<com.example.demo.entity.User>] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.demo.entity.User>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.demo.entity.User>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]] with root cause



com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.demo.entity.User>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1462) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:392) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:252) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3682) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]

at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:380) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:343) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1037) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1020) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:631) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at com.example.demo.service.UserService.getUsers(UserService.java:36) ~[classes/:na]

at com.example.demo.controller.UserController.getUsers(UserController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322]

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322]

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322]

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_322]
```

Comment: with reference to your error logs, it shows that your remote service call of rest template with ParameterizedTypeReference is not working for "List<User>".
Means, after getting response, it is unable to map that response in List<User>.

Comment: Why can't it map the response to the List<User> Or how can it be solved?!

Comment: Azad, please check my answer

Comment: @AbhaleAmol response appear to be correct. Your stacktrace displays the following: " Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.demo.entity.User>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)". You have an exception in deserialization in the first place. Probably you have an interceptor for RestTemplate that is returning the null. The solution is to create the wrapper class ass suggested in the answer. The problem is that in JSON, you have an object that contains a property named User, that property is an array. So you have the wrap the object in first place.

Answer (score 1):

As exception suggest, response can not map to `List<User>`, beside it i suggest to use `Optional` to manage all `null` possibilities as well

```html
yourServiceReturnTypeAsOptional
       .map(vs -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(vs))
              .orElseGet(() ->ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
              .build())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom wrapper class:

```
public class UserList {

private List<User> User;

public List<User> getUser() {
    return this.User;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> User) {
    this.User = User;
}
```

Then:

```
UserList userList =restTemplate.exchange("https://dummyjson.com/
     produts/",HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<UserList.class>(){
            });
List<User> users= userList.getUser();
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in my first post, I have done this procedure too and it is returning null

Comment: I think the variable must be called User and not users, so it can match the json entry "User". private List<User> User;

Comment: @pringi  I have tested with the variable User as you said but received the same error as before